# How do i handle ValueError in this code Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, error-handling, valueerror

I've done this before but i think this error is showing up because I'm not looping the code, the code works only once then on the second attempt is shows an error.

My Code:

```
import string
import time
def timer(x):
    for n in range(x,0,-1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(n)
    print("Times Up"+"\n")
    ask("Time for: ")

def ask(a):
    x=int(input(str(a)))
    print("\n"+"Clock's Ticking")
    timer(x)
try:
    ask("Time for: ")
except ValueError:
    ask("Enter a number to time: ")
```

I want my code to not error when i put in something that isnt a integer for the time but dont know how to loop the exception code until the user enters a integer.

Comment: why not put the exception handling in the `ask` function itself? then the exception will be handled regardless of if it is in a loop or not.

Comment: wowzers 200 iq ok ill try that

Answer (score 0):

Move the exception handling to `ask` function:

```
import string
import time
def timer(x):
    for n in range(x,0,-1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(n)
    print("Times Up"+"\n")
    ask("Time for: ")

def ask(a):
    x = None
    while x is None:
        try:
            x=int(input(str(a)))
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter a number to time!')
    timer(x)

ask("Time for: ")
```